# How to jump from the () to {} when entering if/then conditions or functions in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Right now I am using Qt Creator and when I want to create an if/then statement, I start typing if and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and then enter and the ifthen is autocompleted and my cursor is automatically moved inside the () parentheses after the word if.

Now, I will type the condition, e.g. name != "Adam" and now I want to jump into the {} part (the then part) of the ifthen statement, but when I press tab, it is behaving like a tab and just add 4 spaces after ".

What key combination I have to press so my cursor is moved to the {} part?

I am using arrows for now, but that seems inefficient and not very elegant.

How to do that?

Comment: does using a mouse click count as more elegant?

Comment: the best I have found so far is ctrl + enter. ;(

Comment: sorry for the snarky comment. I tried to do some research, for different motivation (i'd like to turn it off completely, I mean come on, when I hit tab I want a tab not some fancy stuff ;), though I am completely lost what term to look for. I didn't find anything when searching for "shortcuts"...

Comment: Another problem of mine is that in for statement you have for (int x; ; ;) and how thehell am I suppose to go after ; after I type int x. I am better off to type out everything manually and don't use autocomplete for the for loop at all. I can't believe there are no shortcuts for these things you do all the time all day long ;(

Comment: I remember a time where arrow keys on a common keyboard - working in any application were considered as real progress. Ok, Ok, it's some decades ago...